# Custom post type for text box that appears on every page

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to create a custom post type for an entry that will appear on every page of a website. A few other CMS's have a 'globals' entry type for this. How would I go about this using Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most popular way to do this is to use a widget in the installation. Or ACF pro provides a global field - but that's a commercial plugin.